# Number of arrangements of noughts and crosses in grid

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

[image: find the question here please]

The way I went about it is as follows:

- let's consider a 4x4 grid with 15 noughts and 1 cross. This would generate 16 different combinations.
- Now for a 4x4 grid with 4 crosses and 12 noughts, each cross could take 12 different positions and since we have 4 crosses then the number of possible arrangements is 4*12=48.

Is this right or is there a different way of approaching this kind of questions.

Thanks

Comment: The first cross can be put in $16$ places, the second in $15$, the third in $14$ and the fourth in $13$ places. Each of these configurations can be achieved in $4!$ ways, so ...

Comment: May I suggest you pick a more descriptive title?

Comment: Yeah definitely. What do you reckon?

Comment: @SxS How about something like 'Number of Arrangements of Noughts and Crosses in Grid'

Answer (score 2):

If each of the $4$ crosses would have $12$ possibilities, it would be more like $12*12*12*12$, i.e. $12^4$

But that is not right: the first cross has $16$ possibilities, the next one $15$, the next $14$, and the next $13$ ... so that suggests $16*15*14*13$ ...

... but that is not right either!!

Why?

Well, putting the first cross in the top right corner, and the second cross in the top left corner will give the same outcome as when you put the first cross in the top right corner, and the second cross in the top left corner. So, the $16*15*14*13$ formula is *overcounting* the number of possibilities!

In fact, if we *distinguish* between the crosses, then there are $4!$ ways to put the $4$ crosses in $4$ positions, and in the $16*15*14*13$ formula we treat each of those ways as different (i.e. the formula acts as if all the crosses are different).  But since the crosses are all the same, we end up counting each configuration $4!$ times, so we should divide $16*15*14*13$ by $4!$.

Here is how to conceptually think about this: Out of $16$ possible positions, you need to pick $4$ ... that is exactly what the $16 \choose 4$ formula is, and not coincidentally:

$${16 \choose 4} = \frac{16!}{12!4!} = \frac{16*15*14*13}{4!}$$

Comment: I see. So in a way, this problem is similar to how many words can be generated from the letters AAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

Comment: @SxS Exactly!!!